# try to change tcp init cwnd to 10, but fail,how should I do

Tags: linux, performance, gcc, tcp

when i try to change the tcp init cwnd, 
first, when run `ip show route`,show:

```
10.61.0.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.61.0.241
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0  scope link  metric 1002
default via 10.61.0.254 dev eth0  proto static
```

so i run 
`sudo ip route change default via 10.61.0.254 dev eth0  proto static initcwnd 10`
to change the initcwnd to 10,
and after above, i run `ip show route`again:

```
10.61.0.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.61.0.241
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0  scope link  metric 1002
default via 10.61.0.254 dev eth0  proto static  initcwnd 10
```

it seems work.but when i reboot, the value don't reserve.

```
10.61.0.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.61.0.241
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0  scope link  metric 1002
default via 10.61.0.254 dev eth0  proto static
```

How should I do？
my os version info:

```
Linux version 2.6.32-358.18.1.el6.x86_64 (mockbuild@c6b10.bsys.dev.centos.org) (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3) (GCC) ) #1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the ip route commands in the /etc/rc.d/rc.local so they take effect at boot time. 
Kernel 2.6.32 does not have Miller's patch ( https://lwn.net/Articles/426883/) for initcwnd @ 10

You can use ip tcp_metrics or ss to see also more information on a per socket/stream basis